# Querying three tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have query which is querying specific columns in multiple tables (3 tables exactly), but I am not getting result.

In short steps, this is what I want to achieve:

1. SELECT tblhosting.id, tblhosting.domain, tblhosting.userid, tblcoupons.coupon
2. WHERE tblhosting.packageid = tblproducts.id AND tblhosting.domainstatus =  'Active'
3. AND (tblproducts.type =  'hostingaccount'
        OR tblproducts.type = 'server')
4. AND tblcoupons.serviceid = tblhosting.id

BUT RETURN ALL ROWS from tblhosting WHERE conditions are met, and tblcoupons.coupon WHERE tblhosting.id = tblcoupons.serviceid

Query is as follows:

```
SELECT tblhosting.id as tblhostingID, tblhosting.domain, tblhosting.userid, tblcoupons.coupon 
FROM tblhosting, tblproducts
RIGHT JOIN tblcoupons ON id = tblcoupons.serviceid
WHERE tblhosting.userid =1
AND tblhosting.packageid = tblproducts.id
AND tblhosting.domainstatus =  'Active'
AND (tblproducts.type =  'hostingaccount'
     OR tblproducts.type = 'server');
```

coupon | status | userid | serviceid

coupon1
Unused
NULL
1

coupon2
Unused
NULL
NULL

coupon3
Unused
NULL
NULL

coupon4
Unused
NULL
NULL

**EDIT**

I have successfully returned all rows from tblhosting and coupon if is assigned with following query, but I am not sure how to add my WHERE part or include my tblproducts table to return all rows from my tblhosting with coupon or NULL if not assigned WHERE condition is met:

```
AND tblhosting.packageid = tblproducts.id
    AND tblhosting.domainstatus =  'Active'
    AND (tblproducts.type =  'hostingaccount'
         OR tblproducts.type = 'server');
```

Query returning all rows from tblhosting and coupons if assigned:

```
SELECT tblhosting.id AS HostingID, tblhosting.userid AS UserID, tblhosting.domain AS HostingDomain, tblcoupons.coupon AS Coupon
FROM tblhosting
LEFT JOIN tblcoupons ON tblhosting.id = tblcoupons.serviceid
WHERE tblhosting.userid =1;
```

**EDIT 2**

Can I use only LEFT JOIN statements to include two tables?

I have following query which is returning correct results depending on user and WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT tblhosting.id AS HostingID, tblhosting.userid AS UserID, tblhosting.domain AS HostingDomain, tblcoupons.coupon AS Coupon
FROM tblhosting
LEFT JOIN tblcoupons ON tblhosting.id = tblcoupons.serviceid
LEFT JOIN tblproducts ON tblproducts.id = tblhosting.packageid
WHERE tblhosting.userid =1
AND tblhosting.domainstatus =  'Active'
AND (
tblproducts.type =  'hostingaccount'
OR tblproducts.type =  'server'
OR tblproducts.type =  'reselleraccount'
);
```

Comment: don't mix join styles. it's ugly. choose once style, and stick with it.

Comment: Are you sure there are rows that met your conditions? Maybe there are whitespaces in the table. If you are not sure try wildcards.
Is `tblhosting.userid` an int? If not, try to use '1'.

Comment: Also, clarify.  Are you trying to get ALL COUPONS FIRST, and IF there is a match to the given user / hosting product, show IF it has been used/applied?  OR... Are you trying to get all products by a given user, and IF there was a coupon used, show it.  They are subtle, but different.

Comment: "Choose one join style and stick with it"... As long as its explicit JOIN syntax

Comment: @DRapp I want to retrieve all products by a given user where product met condition ('Active' && ( 'server' || 'hostingaccount' )), and then IF there was a coupon used, show it (tblcoupons.coupon)

Answer (score 2):

You are headed the right directions, but you are mixing join styles, which will make for a complicated to understand query. You are also not explicit in which table `id` is coming from in your `ON` clause of your example query.

When I am querying where I want all rows from one table, and rows from another table that match, I always start my `FROM` with the table form which I want all the rows. I like to think of it as "Driving" the query from that table. From there, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to your other table where you only want matching records. Furthermore, if there is a condition on the query from a third table, then you can safely `INNER JOIN` to it since records will be filtered based on it.

All in all, you'll end up with something like:

```
SELECT
    tblhosting.id, tblhosting.domain, tblhosting.userid, tblcoupons.coupon
FROM
    tblhosting
    INNER JOIN tblproducts ON tblhosting.packageid = tblproducts.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblHosting ON tblProducts.id = tblcoupons.serviceid
WHERE
    tblhosting.domainstatus = 'Active'
    AND (tblproducts.type = 'hostingaccount' OR tblproducts.type = 'server')
```

Here we filter records in the `WHERE` clause, and everything else is handled neatly in our `FROM` clause. It's very clear when you read through this one, which tables are being brought in and how they relate to one another.

Comment: just where I was going when asked the question... Just need to add the specific user they were interested in, not ALL users.

Comment: Sounds good. Just keep your Tables and Relationships seperate in your `FROM` and your filtering down in the `WHERE` and you are golden. Also, you could use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to bring `tblProducts` and get the same results. I just switched it over to an `INNER JOIN` because it's more efficient.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Really a LEFT OUTER JOIN to `tblProducts` is going to be equivalent to an INNER JOIN if you are going to filter on `tblProducts`. If you also want records from `tblHosting` even if there isn't a match in `tblProducts` then you could use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and add in the `WHERE` clause something like `OR tblproducts.packageid IS NULL`. That would say "Give me matching records from tblproduct where the type is 'hostingaccount' or 'server' or where there is no match in tblproducts"